# Google PageSpeed Insights with Multiple JavaScript Files

Tags: javascript, pagespeed

I'm optimizing my site based on Google's PageSpeed Insights. It recommends that I "Remove Render-Blocking JavaScript" for several files (names simplified for example's sake):

```
<script src="js/1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'm trying [Patrick Sexton's "Defer Loading Javascript" approach](http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/defer-loading-javascript.html) which only defers one file (`defer.js`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function downloadJSAtOnload() {
    var element = document.createElement("script");
    element.src = "defer.js";
    document.body.appendChild(element);
  }
  if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
  else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
  else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

My question is, how can this approach be modified to include multiple files (i.e. `1.js`, `2.js`, `3.js`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function downloadJSAtOnload() {
        var links = ["js/1.js", "js/2.js", "js/3.js"],
            headElement = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
            linkElement, i;
        for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            linkElement = document.createElement("script");
            linkElement.src = links[i];
            headElement.appendChild(linkElement);
        }
    }
    if (window.addEventListener)
        window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
    else if (window.attachEvent)
        window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
    else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [HeadJS](http://headjs.com/)
for this. I was using it for one of our projects and it was pretty useful.